# What kind of Power BI chart can I use to visualize a percentage of a percentage?

Tags: charts, powerbi

I'm messing around with Visualization in Power BI and cannot find the chart I'm looking for.

Use a dataset pertaining to the 2020 CDC Heart Disease study, I've found that about 28,000 out of 320k people answered "yes" to having some form of Heart Disease.

I'd like to visualize how those 28,000 people's life choices may have lead them to Heart Disease.
The variables I'd like to examine are those who said "yes" to "Smoking", "Alcohol/Drinking", "Diabetes", and "Asthma".

I've tried a pie chart but I do not know how to use Heart Disease[yes] as the basis of comparison.
I've tried Area Charts as well and was unable to figure that out.

Any ideas?

Comment: _Heart Disease[yes] as the basis of comparison._ to what? Is your total dataset (100% of the pie) = everyone with `Heart Disease[yes]`? If so you first need to filter the dataset with that. Then I imagine your pie chart would have one segment containg people that answered yes to one or more of those four options, and the other segment would contain those who didn't. It sounds like you need to come up with a visual representation

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, I've already filtered the data for HeartDisease[yes] people. Now getting a pie chart (or any kind of chart) to show people who've said yes to the other aforementioned categories is where I get lost.

Comment: So your intended pie chart will have two segments? You need a single column in your dataset called "RiskGroup" that is "Y" when someone says yes to _any_ of those questions and "N" otherwise. You can create this as a calculated column. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns then just epxeriment with dragging that column into various spots in the bar chart properties area